# Avoid Interception de InvalidOperationException when modifing a collection

Tags: c#, collections

I have this code to modify the categorie list foreach opened Form

```
var lst = Application.OpenForms.OfType<FrmProduit>();
foreach (var item in lst)
{
    item.getCategorie(Categories.getLastCategorieId());
}
```

Well, the first loop is ok, but then second loop I have the `InvalidOperationExcetion`

Any help please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the `List<T>` ForEach method as follows:

```
Application.OpenForms.OfType<FrmProduit>()
           .ToList()
           .ForEach(i => i.getCategorie(Categories.getLastCategorieId()));
```

This will not throw the error - but if the 'getCategorie' method has a return value, you might want to do something with it. If that's the case, you need:

```
Application.OpenForms.OfType<FrmProduit>()
           .ToList()
           .ForEach(i => 
            {
                var retVal = i.getCategorie(Categories.getLastCategorieId());
                // do something with retVal here...
            });
```

Comment: Well, the problem no more existe, but I have two product form opened, I get only one modified?

Comment: Check the return value of `Application.OpenForms.OfType<FrmProduit>().ToList()` by itself - then you can see if your call to Application.OpenForms is really returning both forms. I would suspect that it isn't for some reason.

Comment: int azaz = Application.OpenForms.OfType<FrmProduit>().Count(); and I got 2 , I make a break point, and step by step, it goes tow time to the getGategorie methode, but still one form is modified; Well if you know any other methode to modify the list, it will be ok

Comment: I think the code above is working OK in that case. There must be another reason why your form is not being modified - but that's outside the scope of this code. I think it's doing what's expected.